# When I put my pointer on paddle1 it says code is unreachable Pylance

Tags: python-3.x

This code is giving me an error:

```
import turtle

wind = turtle.Screen()
wind.title("Ping Pong")
wind.bgcolor("Gray")
wind.setup(width=800, height=600)
wind.tracer(0) #stops the window from updating automaticaly

while True:
    wind.update() #updates the screen every time the loop runs

paddle1 = turtle.Turtle()
paddle1.speed(0)
```

When I put my mouse on paddle1 var it tells me `code in unreachable Pylance`

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

The `while True` loop only calls `wind.update()` and will run it forever, never reaching the `paddle` code.